# Copy all on page button on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello i tried to make copy all button but doesn't work..

I need copy and paste everything in my page with button.

but doesn't work it only paste text , Table form not have values in input form

It only copied table and text

My HTML:

```
<div id="tdiv">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>A01</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" style="width: 100%;" placeholder="Axxxxx">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<button type="button"  onclick="select()">Copy</button>
```

My JavaScript:

```js
function select(id) {    
  window.getSelection().selectAllChildren(document.getElementById("tdiv"));
  document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

Here My Picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDrXD.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you include examples of what the copied data looks like, and what you think it should look like?

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is a promise object returned after the writeText function. If the operation is successful then we catch it with

Html:

```
<div id="tdiv">
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>A01</td>
        <td><input type="text" style="width: 100%;" placeholder="Axxxxx" id="copy-area"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="button" onclick="copy()">
              Copy
          </button>

    <div>
      <textarea id="paste-area" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
      <button type="button" onclick="paste()">Paste</button>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
function copy() {
        let copyArea = document.getElementById('copy-area');
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyArea.value)
        .then(() => {
                alert("text successfuly copied")
            })
      }

      function paste() {
        let pasteArea = document.getElementById('paste-area');
        pasteArea.value = '';

        navigator.clipboard.readText()
          .then((text) => {
            pasteArea.value = text;
          });
      }
```

Updated :

```
<div id="tdiv">
        <table border="1">
          <tr>
            <td>A01</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" style="width: 100%;" placeholder="Axxxxx">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>

      <button type="button" onclick="SelectContents()">Copy</button>

function SelectContents() {
            let elemToSelect = document.getElementById("tdiv");
            if (window.getSelection) { 
                let selection = window.getSelection();
                selection.selectAllChildren(elemToSelect);
            } else {                  
                let range = document.body.createTextRange();
                range.moveToElementText(elemToSelect);
                range.select();
            }
        }
```

Comment: sorry but it not yet, When i trie to paste it to Email box values in form isn't show

Comment: that's because you don't keep the value you're copying in the variable.  where do you want to paste the value you copied from here ? and you're gonna do it through a button ? if you're gonna use a button, show it. How else would I know what you're thinking ?

Comment: I has been uploaded picture that i need to do

please help

Comment: be more specific, please. when I copy the text, Where do I paste it ?

Comment: Paste it to Outlook sir

Comment: I updated my answer. This will do the job. put it on your computer and try it there. Because he needs your permission to copy it.

Comment: srry sir , I think i said is not clear because i'm not good in english langauge 

I need to copy&paste everything in page
Exam
Text with Table Form With values in input form in onetime and paste it with text ,table form and input form with values

Fornow
It can copy and paste only text with table form and input form ,It not have values inside input form

Comment: when you say you want to copy everything on the page, you mean all the elements ? Like: `Table, th, tr , input`

Comment: Yes, It all Element

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check ? If I didn't get what you wanted again, I guess there's nothing I can do.